# Use dask to chunkwise work with smaller pandas df breaks memory limits

Tags: python, dask

I do have the following problem:

**The downside:**
I do have a large amount of data that does not fit a pandas df in memory.

**The upside:**
The data is mostly independent from each other. The only restriction is, that all elements with the same id have to be calculated together in a chunk.

**What I tried:**
Dask looked like a perfect fit for this problem.

I have a dask kubernetes cluster with multiple workers and no problem loading the data from sql database into a dask df.

The calculation itself is not that easy to implement in dask because some functions are missing or problematic with dask (e.g Multiindex, pivot). However because the data is mostly independent I tried to make the calculations chunkwise in pandas. When I call the  `.set_index(id)` function on the dask df all equal id's are in the same partition. Thereby I wanted to iterate over the partitions and make the calculations on a (temporary) pandas df and store the result right away.

The code basically looks like this:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
from distributed import Client

client = Client("kubernetes adress")

#Loading:
for i in range(x):
    df_chunk = load_from_sql
    future = client.scatter(df_chunk)
    futures.append(future)

dask_df = dd.from_delayed(futures, meta=df_chunk)

dask_df = dask_df.set_index("id")
dask_df.map_partitions(lambda part: calculation(part).compute()
```

where

```
def calculation(part):
    part = # do something in pandas
    part.to_csv/to_sql # store data somwhere
    del part / client.cancel(part) # release memory of temporary pandas df
```

With small amounts of data this runs smoothly however with a lot data the memory of the workers becomes full and the process stops with a cancelled error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong or are there any alternatives with dask to work memory efficient with chunkwise data from a dask df?

Loading the data directly in chunks from the database is currently not an option.

Comment: I think the problem is that each of your partition is still too big. Thus each calculation() is expected to process too much data. Without knowing how you are reading and processing the data at the "part" in your code example, its hard to tell. But first, what is the size of each partition?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. The calculation part works perfectly fine with a pandas df equal to the partition size. I tried several possibilities here but in general I read a chunksize of 100k to 1million and one chunk equals roughly the size of one partition of the dask df.